# Replace point markers with custom images

Tags: r, r-highcharter

```
dfr <- data.frame(
    x = c("Denmark", "Denmark", "South Korea", "South Korea", "Yemen", "Yemen"),
    sex = c("Man", "Woman", "Man", "Woman", "Man", "Woman"),
    y = c(181.4, 167.2, 174.9, 157.4, 159.9, 153.97), image = c("https://i.imgur.com/vs0YaFR.png", "https://i.imgur.com/e9SbUdB.png", "https://i.imgur.com/qRYQ5Sk.png", "https://i.imgur.com/e9SbUdB.png", "https://i.imgur.com/XG13e1K.png", "https://i.imgur.com/e9SbUdB.png")
)

library(highcharter)
hchart(dfr, "scatter", hcaes(x = x, y = y, group = sex), showInLegend = T)
```

I would like to use custom images as marker instead of the point symbol. Found this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpintor/r28a3g4q/30/) showing the end result.

[image]